# Sum cells with a colored background, separately from other cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I just want to be able to plug in data, then have the cells that I color a specific color, Yellow for example, totaled into another cell specifically because of the background color.

I've found a couple ways to do this but they seem to involve requiring either another column with the actual color name in every sell to use as a reference for the formula, or it requires me to use filters and another formula. One approach used vb but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

I just want to be able to plug data into cells then have the ones that are colored, SUM'ed up into another cell

Comment: I changed the title of your question as I don't think you require separate *calculation*. (That would imply you don't want formulas in other cells to be calculate.)  I think you want the coloured cells *summed* into separate cells.  If I'm incorrect, feel free to rollback my change [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51509861/revisions).

Comment: How many colors are there?  Do they change?  You mentioned you didn't like the solution that involved adding a column... this raises the question, "where are the results supposed to go?" Perhaps examples of **what you have** and **what you want to have** would helpful.  Also, **how many colours** are there in use, and, will that **change**? (Does this need to dynamically add/remove totals?) Generally on [so] you're expected to provide your own code in the form of an [mcve] and show where the problems is. (That said, this does sound like an interesting, albeit unusual, coding challenge!)

Comment: ...also, would this encompass a specific range of cells or a worksheet or the entire workbook?  Does this encompass *any* colour? (What about white or "No Fill" - which are 2 separate things)? How often should this update the totals - manually, or on schedule, or if something changes?

Comment: Thanks @ashleedawg, the rewording of my question was perfectly fine. Also I am aware that we need to usually show at least some attempt at coding ourselves. It's been awhile since I've asked a question on here so I can't remember if I can post a pic of what I'm working on or not. That would actually be far more helpful. I don't think it's anything difficult, I'm thinking it might require a vb script.